# Why is pkg-config --cflags openssl returning nothing on RHEL 6.8?

Tags: rhel, openssl, pkg-config

I'm running on a RHEL 6.8 Linux machine. I am seeking to build various packages from source tarballs/git-repos/whatefer *without* changing the system configuration (under root or sudo).

I'm running on a RHEL 6.8 machine:

```
bash-4.1$ cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.8 (Santiago)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

`openssl-devel` is installed:

```
bash-4.1$ rpm -q -a | grep openssl
openssl-1.0.1e-48.el6.i686
openssl098e-0.9.8e-20.el6_7.1.x86_64
openssl098e-0.9.8e-20.el6_7.1.i686
openssl-devel-1.0.1e-48.el6.i686
openssl-1.0.1e-48.el6.x86_64
openssl-devel-1.0.1e-48.el6.x86_64
```

So I expect that this command to return some output, so that when I build packages from source that use pkg-config, they will find the value of CFLAGS they need:

```
bash-4.1$ pkg-config --cflags openssl
```

But it returns just a newline. Why?

Further debugging:

Show what file it is using:

```
bash-4.1$ pkg-config --debug --list-all 2>&1 | grep 'Will find package.*openssl'
Will find package 'openssl' in file '/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/openssl.pc'
```

Show the file it should be reading:

```
bash-4.1$ cat /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/openssl.pc
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib64
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenSSL
Description: Secure Sockets Layer and cryptography libraries and tools
Version: 1.0.1e
Requires: 
Libs: -L${libdir} -lssl -lcrypto
Libs.private: -Wl,-z,relro -ldl -lz -L/usr/lib -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lcom_err -lk5crypto -lresolv
Cflags: -I${includedir} -I/usr/include
```

Widening the grep out:

```
bash-4.1$ pkg-config --debug --list-all 2>&1 | grep 'openssl'
File 'openssl.pc' appears to be a .pc file
Will find package 'openssl' in file '/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/openssl.pc'
Looking for package 'openssl'
Looking for package 'openssl-uninstalled'
Reading 'openssl' from file '/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/openssl.pc'
Parsing package file '/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/openssl.pc'
Unknown keyword 'Libs.private' in '/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/openssl.pc'
Removing -I/usr/include from cflags for openssl
Removing -I/usr/include from cflags for openssl
Removing -L /usr/lib64 from libs for openssl
Adding 'openssl' to list of known packages, returning as package 'openssl'
openssl                     OpenSSL - Secure Sockets Layer and cryptography libraries and tools
bash-4.1$
```

Hmmm what is that `Removing -I/usr/include from cflags for openssl` doing there?

Also, the `Cflags` variable is defined. Is that a bug? Should it be `cflags` instead?

Also, I've downloaded and built my own `pkg-config`, version 0.29.2, and it gives the same behavior. So I'm suspecting a bug in the `openssl.pc` file, but am not sure.

Even so, what is the fix other than exporting hardcoded values of `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` just prior to calling the various packages `./configure` scripts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like `pkg-config` de-duplicates flags and also skips "default" paths, like /usr/include.

See,

```
$ printf "Name: whatever\nVersion: 1\nDescription: bla\nCflags: -I/usr/include" > /tmp/x.pc
$ pkg-config --cflags  /tmp/x.pc

$ printf "Name: whatever\nVersion: 1\nDescription: bla\nCflags: -I/usr/includeX" > /tmp/y.pc
$ pkg-config --cflags  /tmp/y.pc
-I/usr/includeX
```

These default directories are set at pkg-config's build time, see README.md in the sources:

```
./configure \
     --prefix=/opt/pkgconf \
     --with-system-libdir=/lib:/usr/lib \
     --with-system-includedir=/usr/include
```

You can disable that behavior at runtime via environment variable:

```
$ PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS=1 pkg-config --cflags  /tmp/x.pc
-I/usr/include
```

or override the built-in default:

```
$ PKG_CONFIG_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH="/whatever" pkg-config --cflags  /tmp/x.pc
-I/usr/include
```

Recent pkg-config also has commandline options `--keep-system-cflags` and `--keep-system-libs`

Comment: Thanks! https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html is the guide which says "pkg-config needs to output both sets of link flags in this case to ensure that the statically linked application will find all the necessary symbols. On the other hand, it will always output all the Cflags".  That documentation says nothing about deduplication, so seems like perhaps they forgot to update the docs.  Upon further thought, it probably does make sense that `-I/usr/include` is excluded IFF the compiler has `/usr/include` in its default include paths.

Comment: Where is the `README.md` you referenced?  I cannot find it online. I did find a `README` file at https://cgit.freedesktop.org/pkg-config/tree/README

Comment: @bgoodr The README is here https://github.com/pkgconf/pkgconf. The mentioned environment variables are documented in the man page `man pkg-config`

Comment: Understood. Must be a website bug: https://github.com/pkgconf/pkgconf/issues/117

Comment: @bgoodr Just noticed that `pkg-config` and `pkgconfig` are two different implementations. They should be interchangeable but may have different bugs and documentation. I guess they forked pkg-config because it has an annoying dependency on glib, so it's hard to build on exotic systems.

Comment: Yep! The reply to https://github.com/pkgconf/pkgconf/issues/117 confirms it.